# Truth value of a string in python

Tags: python

```
if <boolean> :
   # do this
```

boolean has to be either True or False.

then why

```
if "poi":
   print "yes"
```

output:
yes

i didn't get why yes is printing , since "poi" is nether True or False.

Comment: Related: [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/4518341)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In python, any string except an empty string defaults to `True`

ie,

```
if "MyString":
    # this will print foo
    print("foo")

if "":
    # this will NOT print foo
    print("foo")
```

Comment: same is true for list and other data types, isn't it ?

Comment: "defaults to `True`" is not really correct. How about "evaluates to `True` in a Boolean context"?

Comment: naveen yadav, yes, it is true for all built-in collection types. Empty collections are False, non-empty collections are True. A string is a sequence, which is a type of collection.

Answer (score 39):

Python will do its best to evaluate the "truthiness" of an expression when a boolean value is needed from that expression.

The rule for strings is that an empty string is considered `False`, a non-empty string is considered `True`.  The same rule is imposed on other containers, so an empty dictionary or list is considered `False`, a dictionary or list with one or more entries is considered `True`.

The `None` object is also considered false.

A numerical value of `0` is considered false (although a string value of `'0'` is considered true).

All other expressions are considered `True`.

Details (including how user-defined types can specify truthiness) can be found here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html.

Comment: I believe Python will always test __len__() of any class that has one, and consider a result of 0 to mean the object evaluates to `false` in a boolean context.  This is pretty close to the same thing as imposing the same rule even on user-defined classes (you'd have to deliberately return some non-intuitive value from your __len__() method, or leave it out entirely, to avoid following the same rule as built-ins).

Comment: For anyone reading the above answer : make sure you actually read the doc (either the above link or here : http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)

Comment: Equivalent documentation for Python 3: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__

Comment: Just in case anyone is confused by something like `'a' or 'b'` returning `'a'` instead of `True`, note that `and` and `or` are "short circuit operators", and "When used as a general value and not as a Boolean, the return value of a short-circuit operator is the last evaluated argument."  Since `'a'` evaluates as `True`, the whole expression must be true, and so the truth value of `'b'` is not even evaluated.  https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions

Answer (score 10):

What is happening here is Python' supplement of **implicit `bool()` constructor** after the `if`, Because anything followed by `if` should be resolved to be boolean. In this context your code is equivalent to

```
if bool("hello"):
   print "yes"
```

According to Python `bool(x)` constructor accepts anything and decides the truthiness based on below cases

- If x is integer, Only `0` is `False` everything else is `True`
- If x is float, Only `0.0` is `False` everything else is True`
- If x is list, Only `[]` is `False` everything else is `True`
- If x is set/dict, Only `{}` is `False` everything else is `True`
- If x is tuple, Only `()` is `False` everything else is `True`
- If x is string, Only `“"` is `False` everything else is `True`. Be aware that `bool(“False”)` will return to `True`

Here is the log for the cases I listed above

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Feb 25 2015, 21:28:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(-1)
True
>>> bool(0.0)
False
>>> bool(0.02)
True
>>> bool(-0.10)
True
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1,2])
True
>>> bool(())
False
>>> bool(("Hello","World"))
True
>>> bool({})
False
>>> bool({1,2,3})
True
>>> bool({1:"One", 2:"Two"})
True
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool("Hello")
True
>>> bool("False")
True
```

Comment: Don't forget that bool(None) evaluates to False.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, a non-empty string is considered "truthy," which means it is treated as equivalent to True in a boolean context. This is why in your example:

```
if "poi":
  print("yes")
```

In this code the poi is considered as true and hence, the output is 'yes'

In Boolean contexts, values like 0, False, None, and empty strings "" are considered "falsy," meaning they are treated as equivalent to False.

Even if 'poi' is different from 'true' it's still considered as a true in the Boolean context.

If you really want to do real coding, then you will need to replace the poi by true.

```
if True:
  print("yes")
```

This will also give you the result as 'yes'.