# How can I keep track of a variable during a For loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Basically, this is what I am trying to do.  I have an CSV file that I read in using Python 3. So, here is the basic layout of the rows:

```
Row1: On
Row2: <empty>
Row3: <empty>
Row4: On
Row5: On
Row6: <empty>
Row7: Off
Row8: <empty>
```

The code to access this would be:

```
for row in file:
     var = row[0]
     print(var)
```

The output I would like to see for each line after running the script would be:

```
for row in file:
     print(var)

On
On
On
On
On
On
Off
Off
```

I am not sure how to do it, but I am trying to keep track of the variable as the program moves through the for loop.  Here is the logic:

```
for loop:
  1.  If row[0] has the string 'On', then assign 'On' to var
  2.  If the next row[0] is empty, then I want the var to retain the previous value of 'On'.
  3.  Var will not change from 'On' until row[0] has a different value such as 'Off'.  Then, Var will be assigned 'Off'.
```

Hopefully this question makes sense.  I am not sure how to do this in Python 3.

Comment: What do you mean when you say a row is empty?  A blank line?  Commas with no values between them?  Empty strings?

Comment: So just declare `var = None` outside the loop?  Then, `if row != "": var = row`?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
# set an initial value for `var`
var = None
for row in file:
    # `row` should now contain the text content of a line
    if row:
        # if the string is not empty
        # set var to the value of the string
        var = row
    # print the value of var
    print(var)
```

In Python, [empty strings are "falsey"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18491862/399726) while non-empty strings are "truthy". By using the statement `if row:` we would only proceed into the `if` statement when `row` contains non-empty strings, such as `"On"`, or `"Off"`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple if/else will do

```
var = some_initial_value
for row in file:
     var = row[0] if row[0] else var
     print(var)
```