# Why doesn't re.match("c", "cat") return true?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Why does

```
not re.match("c", "cat")
```

return False, but

```
re.match("c", "cat")
```

Does not return True but instead returns the location of the object in memory. I can't find a way to make this statement return true, but I know it is true because:

```
if re.match("c", "cat"):
    print "Yes!"
```

returns "Yes!".

As I said, this is of no practical significance, at least not at the moment, but it does puzzle me.

Comment: *I can't find a way to make this statement return true* -- just explicitly convert it to `bool`: `bool(re.match("c", "cat"))`.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing - everything in Python can be evaluated in a Boolean context (using `if`, `not`, etc.). The match will return a result (truthy) or `None` (falsy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `bool()` to convert to a boolean value (`true` `/` `false`):

```
bool(re.match("c", "cat")) == true
```

When you use `re.match("c", "cat")` in your `if` statement, it is automatically converted to a boolean value, `true`, that is why it will `return` `Yes!`

Using `not` will automatically convert it to a boolean value, then invert it, therefore:

```
not re.match("c", "cat") == false
```

Answer (score 4):

The function [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) if there is a match, or `None` if there's not.

To create a bool from that you can use:

```
if re.match(...) is not None:
```

However, in Python that's not strictly necessary: take a look at e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/python-truth-value-of-python-string) for more on Python's "truthy" and "falsy" values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, focus on this:

```
not re.match("c", "cat")
```

Here `re.match("c", "cat")` will return the "location of the object in memory", as you said. That's something not False.

So now, `not re.match("c", "cat")` will result in:

> not not False

which results to:

> False

Of course, this kind of thinking can be applied to logical conditions too, like a condition of an if statement.

Comment: I got bamboozled by all the negations, was correct at second glance.