# Selenium Python check if variable value is not blank. I am getting False but there is a value

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a function which checks if the variables are blank.  If the variables do have a value I would like the function to return True.
If the variables do not have a value assigned I would like the function to return False.

My function is returning False if there is a value.  I want the function to return True if the variable has a value.
My logic seems incorrect.  I need some help please to get it right.

My function is:

```
def is_view_report_showing_results(self):
    usn_row_cell1_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]')
    source_fields_row_cell1_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')
    #return (usn_row_cell1_element.text is not None) and (source_fields_row_cell1_element.text is not None)
    return not (usn_row_cell1_element.text == "") and (source_fields_row_cell1_element.text == "")

self.assertTrue(reports_view_results_page.is_view_report_showing_results(), "Problem with viewing report. Please see log for details")
```

The value in the variable usn_row_cell1_element is a string value "2"
The value in the variable source_fields_row_cell1_element is a string "Address"

I am going to try this way:

```
def is_view_report_showing_results3(self):
    usn_row_cell1_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]')
    source_fields_row_cell1_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')
    #return (usn_row_cell1_element.text is not None) and (source_fields_row_cell1_element.text is not None)
    if (usn_row_cell1_element.text == "") and (source_fields_row_cell1_element.text == "") == False:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check for the ["truthiness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/python-truth-value-of-python-string) of the values:

```
return usn_row_cell1_element.text and source_fields_row_cell1_element.text
```

Or, if you want to pass the test if at least one of the values is non-empty, use `or`:

```
return usn_row_cell1_element.text or source_fields_row_cell1_element.text
```

Note that in this case the function would return a string value, but this is not a problem since, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue), `assertTrue` would do the `bool(x) is True` check.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks for your help.