# How to test whether one of three keys is in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, contains

How can I test whether any of `a` or `b` or `c` are keys in a dict?

Are there some short and simple methods in Python?

With two keys, I can use

```
if a or b in my_dict.keys():
```

How can I do the same with three keys?

Comment: No, you can't use that code; it doesn't at all do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to check any of the condition is `True`. Let say your `dict` is:

```
my_dict = {
  'x': 1,
  'y': 2,
  'a': 3   # `a` key in dict
}
```

In order to check any item exists in dictionary's keys, you may do:

```
>>> values_to_check = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # list of value to check
#                     v You do not need `.keys()` as by default `in` checks in keys 
>>> any(item in my_dict for item in values_to_check)
True
```

Comment: Or more succintly - `if my_dict.keys() & values_to_check`... (or `if my_dict.viewkeys() & values_to_check` in Python 2.x)

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: `if a or b in my_dict.keys():` doesn't do what you think. For example:

```
>>> 'a' or 'b' in {'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}.keys()
'a'
```

What actually happens there is the result of [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): first, `'a'` is evaluated, and if it's ["truthy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/python-truth-value-of-python-string), it's returned without checking anything else. Only if `'a'` were "falsy" would `'b'` (and *only* `'b'`) be checked against the dict's keys.

It's a little clearer what Python actually does if you add some parentheses to your code:

```
if (a) or (b in my_dict.keys()):
```

The way you'd actually have to write the two-value version of the code in that style would be:

```
if a in my_dict.keys() or b in my_dict.keys():
    # ...
```

**On to your actual question:**

To test an arbitrary number of values (including two), you have two choices:

```
if any(x in my_dict.keys() for x in (a, b, c)):
    # ...
```

or

```
if my_dict.keys() & {a, b, c}:  # replace keys with viewkeys in Python 2
    # ...
```

Which one of those you go for is largely down to personal taste ... although the `any(...)` solution is necessary if you require actual `True` or `False` results, rather than "truthy" values that work in an `if` statement.