# Finding the Differentiation Condition between 2 list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am a newbie in python and I was trying to figure out, how do I differentiate between 2 lists which are as shown below

```
['11-10-2017', '12:15 PM', 'B.ARTS', 'Linguistics', '', '', 'German', 'Name']
```

And

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

The Problem is, that both the lists have `''` element, and I want a solid Condition which satisfies that if a list has an item which is a string and not `''`. It is also possible that list has 7 `''` and just one item is a string.

Comment: `filter(None, your_list)` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: i need a condition.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with the list as argument :

```
>>> any(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
False
>>> any(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Test', ''])
True
```

If there's any element which is truthy (i.e. non empty), it will return `True`.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I wanted, but it was the closest to my expected output.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to filter empty strings from a list:

```
lst = ['11-10-2017', '12:15 PM', 'B.ARTS', 'Linguistics', '', '', 'German', 'Name']
[item for item in lst if item]
# ['11-10-2017', '12:15 PM', 'B.ARTS', 'Linguistics', 'German', 'Name']
```

> I want a solid Condition which satisfies that if a list has an item which is a string and not `''`

The condition is `if item`.  To clarify, `''` is an empty string.  During iteration, if the `item` is `''`, the condition is `False` and thus the item is excluded from the result.  Otherwise, the condition is `True` and the result is added to the list. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python).

This behavior is because [all objects in Python have "truthiness"](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) - all objects are assumed `True` except for a few, such as `False`, `0`, `""`, `None` and empty collections.

Comment: Shouldn't it be same as `filter(None, lst)`? Please see my earlier comment.

Comment: @Unni, yes `list(filter(None, lst))` gives the same output in a different way.  `filter` is the functional approach  that uses an inherent default predicate, which may not be obvious to the OP.  Here I am using a list comprehension to demonstrate that `''` is an empty, Falsey string, which gets filtered because it negates the condition.  Still, I feel the OP may be looking for something else, which requires clarification in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a condition which is satisfied if there are no `''`, in the
>   string.

You can use `all` for checking this.

```
In [1]: s1 = ['11-10-2017', '12:15 PM', 'B.ARTS', 'Linguistics', '', '', 'German', 'Name']
In [2]: s2 = ['11-10-2017', '12:15 PM']

In [4]: all(x for x in s1)
Out[4]: False

In [5]: all(x for x in s2)
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: I need a condition which is satisfied if there are no `''`, in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see if there is not a `''` in your list is to use `not in`:

```
tests = [
    ['11-10-2017', '12:15 PM', 'B.ARTS', 'Linguistics', '', '', 'German', 'Name'], 
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', 'x', '', '']]

for t in tests:
    print '' not in t, t
```

Which would display:

```
False ['11-10-2017', '12:15 PM', 'B.ARTS', 'Linguistics', '', '', 'German', 'Name']
False ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
True ['a', 'b', 'c']
False ['', '', '', '', '', 'x', '', '']
```