# How to use 'while 'variable':'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and was looking around for a code for a function where the user inputs and integer and the function adds and returns the sum of the digits of the number.

The code looked like this:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return s
```

So I know how a while loop works, but I can't wrap my head around (nor am able to find anything on Google) about how this works. I thought While loops always have a condition such as 'while n<10' or the sort.

What exactly is 'while n:' saying? How does this code work exactly? How does the code know how to stop running, and how exactly does it even return the sum of the digits (all I see it doing is returning the remainder of s/n).

Thanks for the help and sorry for any stupid questions.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Objects can be "truthy" or "falsey". For example, non-zero `float` objects are "truthy", empty containers (`[], (), {})` are *falsey*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python) . From the answer to that question: `A numerical value of 0 is considered false (although a string value of '0' is considered true).

All other expressions are considered True. `

Answer (score 0):

`while n:` is equivalent to `while n!=0:` (in this case, when you're dealing with numbers). Since each value in python has a Boolean value, for any number that is different from zero, `bool(n) == True`, if n equals zero, `bool(n) == False`.

That function can be written like (Thanks to @Jean-FrançoisFabre for suggesting the use of `divmod`):

```
def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n != 0:
        n, t = divmod(n, 10)  # to not use division and modulo separately
        # n has the value of n//10, t has the value of n%10
        s += t
    return s

print(sum_digits(154)) # => 10
print(sum_digits(134)) # => 8
print(sum_digits(987)) # => 24
```

Comment: or `n,s = divmod(n,10)` to replace modulo + division

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, you're right about `divmod`, but he's incremeting `s`, not setting it, so the div part needs to be set to a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

`while` implicitly calls `bool` on the argument. So as long as `bool(n)` in your example is `True` the `while` loop continues.

And [Pythons documentation for builtin types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) states that any number except zero is considered True:

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns `False` or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object. Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: None and False.
> - zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
> - empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)

So basically the `while n` loop will continue until `n` becomes zero (or you `break` or `return` or `raise`...)