# Converting different data types into each other

Tags: python, types

```
my_boolean = bool("Hello")
print(my_boolean)
```

When I run this code in python, the output is True.What is the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python

Comment: Strictly speaking you're not converting a value from string to boolean, because you're loosing information, "hello" as input would result in the same output as "bye bye".

Answer (score 1):

Because it checks if the string is empty:

- Empty return False
- Not Empty return True