# Python code not doing what I think it's supposed to

Tags: python, replit

I have written some code with conditional statements and I don't think it's supposed to do what happens.

I tried to rewrite the code many times.

```
def main():
def enter():
  inputenter = input("Please enter a number. ")
  if inputenter in ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"):
    getready()
  else:
    inputstartagain = input("Invalid Request") 
def getready():
  inputgetreadybrush = input("Did you brush your teeth? ")
  if inputgetreadybrush == "Yes" or "yes" or "y" or "Y":
    inputgetreadyshower = input("Did you shower? ")
    if inputgetreadyshower == "Yes" or "yes" or "y" or "Y":
      print("Your output is: I already got ready. ")
    elif inputgetreadyshower == "No" or "no" or "N" or "n":
      print("Your output is: Shower ")
    else:
      print("")
  elif inputgetreadybrush == "No" or "no" or "n" or "N":
    inputgetreadyshower1 = input("Did you shower? ")
    if inputgetreadyshower1 == "Yes" or "yes" or "Y" or "y":
      print("Your output is: Brush ")
    elif inputgetreadyshower1 == "No" or "no" or "n" or "N":
      print("Your output is: Brush and Shower ")
  else:
    print("")

main()
```

I expected the output of (these are the answers to the if statements) 1,y,n to be "Your output is: Shower" but the actual output is "Your output is: I already got ready. " for everything.

Comment: [How to write a good title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: See [truth value of a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python). When you do `or "yes"`, that's essentially putting `or True` in your conditional, causing it to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why you try to write so many words to a simple **yes/no** answer?*

Will be more easy if you will try to check just the first letter. In this case you will see if first letter of the answer is "**y**" or "**n**"

For the example your *getready()* function will look more clear if you will have this:

```py
def getready():
    inputgetreadybrush = input("Did you brush your teeth? ")

    if inputgetreadybrush.lower()[:1] == "y":
        inputgetreadyshower = input("Did you shower? ")

        if inputgetreadyshower.lower()[:1] == "y":
              print("Your output is: I already got ready. ")

        else:
              print("Your output is: Shower ")

    elif inputgetreadybrush.lower()[:1] == "n":
        inputgetreadyshower1 = input("Did you shower? ")

        if inputgetreadyshower1.lower()[:1] == "y":
          print("Your output is: Brush ")

        else:
          print("Your output is: Brush and Shower ")

    # In case you want to truck if anithing else was press:
    else:
        print(f"What do you mean {inputgetreadybrush.lower()}? I do not understand...")
```

In this case will be more easy for humans to know what is happen there much faster. And will look more processional :))

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to `or` conditions like `inputgetreadybrush == "Yes" or "yes" or "y" or "Y":`

It will always be true. It is interpreted as `(inputgetreadybrush == "Yes") or "yes" or "y" or "Y":`

And if the answer isn't Yes, the next test, `or 'yes'` will be counted as true.

It could be better written as:

`inputgetreadybrush[0].lower() == 'y':`

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your conditions to the correct syntax:

```
if (inputgetreadybrush == "Yes") or (inputgetreadybrush == "yes") or (inputgetreadybrush == "y") or (inputgetreadybrush == "Y"):
```

This solves all of your problems.