# Python while loop only checking first if statement (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm doing a command to my discord bot, which sends back a response depending on the users response to the command. I have a while loop, where I go through all possible answers and if none of them are true, then go to else statement. However, every time the loop runs, it returns the answer depending by the first statement (if answer is high) and doesn't actually seem to care about the other elif statements. Does this have something to do with the message.content parts, since they don't seem to work at all? Here's the loop:

EDIT: added the whole event

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if '.highlow' in message.content:
            randomnumber = random.randint(0,100)
            hintnumber = random.randint(0,100)
            channel = message.channel
            await channel.send('Satunnainen luku on valittu väliltä ``0-100``.\n'
                            f'Vihjeesi on ``{hintnumber}``.\n'
                            'Vastaa kirjoittamalla ``high``, ``low`` tai ``vihje``.')

            def check(message):
                return message.content == 'high' or 'low' or 'vihje' and message.channel == channel

            msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

            while True:
                if message.author != self.client.user:
                    if 'high' in message.content:
                        if randomnumber > hintnumber:
                            await channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten voitit pelin!'.format(msg))
                            break
                        elif randomnumber < hintnumber:
                            await channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten hävisit pelin!'.format(msg))
                            break
                    elif 'low' in message.content:
                        if randomnumber < hintnumber:
                            await channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten voitit pelin!'.format(msg))
                            break
                        elif randomnumber > hintnumber:
                            await channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten hävisit pelin!'.format(msg))
                            break
                    elif 'vihje' in message.content:
                        if randomnumber == hintnumber:
                            await channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten voitit pelin!'.format(msg))
                            break
                        elif randomnumber != hintnumber:
                            await channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten hävisit pelin!'.format(msg))
                            break
                    else:
                        await channel.send('Tuo ei ole oikea vaihtoehto!')
                        break
```

The command is in a cog.

Comment: What is the command/how did you define it?

Comment: @Dominik I edited the whole event to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `check()`. Your conditional looks incorrect.

`message.content == 'high' or 'low' or 'vihje' and message.channel == channel` will always be `True`

It looks to me like you want `check()` to return `True` when `message.content` is one of high, low or vihje, and when `message.channel` is `channel`. Unfortunately, your syntax for the first condition is incorrect, it will always evaluate to `True` because of the [truthiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python) of Python `str`S. The effect of this is that `check()` can return `True` even when `message.content` is 'pinkalicious' or even `None`. Rewrite `check()` as:

```py
def check(message):
    return message.content in {'high', 'low', 'vihje'} and message.channel == channel
```

Your conditional is actually evaluated as:

```py
(message.content == 'high') or ('low') or ('vihje') and (message.channel == channel)
```

Since non-empty `str`S evaluate to `True`, your conditional is this:

```py
(message.content == 'high') or (True) or (True) and (message.channel == channel)

# Which reduces to
True
```

If you want to see the truthiness of Python strings for yourself, run the following snippet:

```py
if '':
    print('empty string is True')
else:
    print('empty string is False')

if 'foo':
    print('non-empty string is True')
else:
    print('non-empty string is False')

if 'false':
    print('"false" is True')
else:
    print('"false" is False')
```

Comment: I changed the check function to what you suggested, however now I'm getting this error: 

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: @tontsa28 The error should be self-explanatory: The bot or the user is missing permissions. Have a look at the following: [Error code 50013](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#json-json-error-codes)

Comment: @Dominik yeah it is self-explanatory, I was just wondering if the permissions are missing from the user or the bot. Managed to fix it, the bot was missing permissions on a private channel.