# Why 'and not' gets executed in this if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

From my understanding, `and` is a short-circuit operator as explained in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). But, why the part c gets printed every I run the code below?

My solution: `if ('RB' in t) and (not ',' in t): ...`, but what I want is an explanation.

```
test = '977'

if 'RB' and '+' in test:
    print('a')
    test = int(test.replace('RB+', '')) * 1000
elif ',' and 'RB' in test:
    print('b')
    temp_test = test.replace(',', '')
    test = int(temp_test.replace('RB', '')) * 1000
elif 'RB' and not ',' in test:
    print('c')
    test = int(test.replace('RB', '')) * 1000
else:
    test = int(test)

print(test)
```

Ouput

```
c
977000
```

Comment: It's parsed as `if 'RB' and (not ',' in test):`

Comment: "why the part c gets printed every I run the code below?". Because there's no comma in `test`.

Comment: All of your conditions are effectively ignoring `'RB'` because that's always truthy by itself. `if 'RB' and '+' in test:` is equivalent to `if '+' in test:`

Comment: For example, in your first `if`, the expression `'RB'` is `truthy` all by itself, so it can be rewritten as: `if True and '+' in test:`, so the `True and` can be removed, leaving you with `if '+' in test:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are effectively checking the 'truthiness' of the string 'RB, which is `True`. See:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=Python%20will%20do%20its%20best,empty%20string%20is%20considered%20True%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python#:%7E:text=3%20Answers&text=Python%20will%20do%20its%20best,empty%20string%20is%20considered%20True%20).

Your third elif breaks down as:

`elif ('RB') and (not ',' in test'):`

You probably want:

```
if 'RB' in test and '+' in test:
    print('a')
    test = int(test.replace('RB+', '')) * 1000
elif ',' in test and 'RB' in test:
    print('b')
    temp_test = test.replace(',', '')
    test = int(temp_test.replace('RB', '')) * 1000
elif 'RB' in test and not ',' in test:
    print('c')
    test = int(test.replace('RB', '')) * 1000
else:
    test = int(test)

print(test)
```