# Python going through all if statements even if the if doesn’t match

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have a calculator script, and I have a variable for the operator, number 1 and number 2, this is what it looks like

```
Operator = input(“operator: “)
Num1 = input(“num1 here: “)
Num2 = input(“num2 here: “)

If Operator == “x” or “*”:
 #code
```

I have one of these for all four main math equations but it’s goes through all the ifs and elifs in order even if the ‘operator’ input doesn’t match. Note I have pyttsx3 installed and a text to speech is in the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison needs to check both conditions.
It should look like:

```
If Operator=='x' or Operator=='*'
```

Right now it's evaluating like:

```
If (Operator=='x') or ('*'==True)
```

In python a string (like '*') will evaluate as 'True', so your code is always being executed.

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator returns the first element if it is truthy, else the second element. Then `if` looks at what it gets. In this case `(Operator == "x") or "*"` evaluates to `"*"`, which in turn is truthy. So the `if` block is entered.

What you would like to do is probably something like

```py
if ( Operator == "x" ) or ( Operator == "*" ):
  # code
```

To back my claim, you can find the definition of `or` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

The string `"*"` is not empty, so it evaluates to true. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18491862/2550406).